# Which Guard fired GuardsCheckEnd?

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards

We have a few router guards that protect different parts of our app.
In some cases, but not in all, we want to do things when the guard returns false.

```
router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof GuardsCheckEnd){
    if (!event.shouldActivate){
      //do stuff
    }
  }
});
```

The above code checks if any guard failed. We want to `//do stuff` only when a specific guard failed.
Is there a way to find out which guard failed?

Comment: Why don't you add that logic into guard?

Comment: There are several guards that require this logic, and only one that doesn't. If that's what it takes I'll do it, but there should be a cleaner answer.

Comment: Also, the guard is much higher up in the route hierarchy, so it won't see the full path the user requested. Which is what we need for the `//do stuff`.

Comment: Wild guess, but could you add some property to guard, which would be available in event?

Comment: I don't think the guard is available in the event. https://angular.io/api/router/GuardsCheckEnd

Comment: Then I suggest you create a service to hold state - guard will set activate true/false, and wherever you subscribe you can check for that guard value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want to know which guards fail, so you should record their value in guard service. This way it will be available to you at all times.

First guard

```js
// FirstGuard
constructor(private guardService: GuardService) {}

canActivate() boolean {
  const canActivate = //some logic
  this.guardService.set('firstGuard', canActivate);
  return canActivate;
}
```

```js
export class GuardService {
  private data = {};

  public set(guardName: string, value: boolean): void {
    this.data[guardName] = value;
  }

  public get(guardName: string): boolean {
    return this.data[guardName] ?? false; // choose default
  }

  public clear(): void {
    this.data = {};
  }
}
```

Where this interests you

```js
router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof GuardsCheckStart) {
    // Make sure you don't have results from past events
    this.guardService.clear();
  }
  if (event instanceof GuardsCheckEnd){
    if (!event.shouldActivate){
      if (this.guardService.get('firstGuard')) {
        // do stuff
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Since we're using`@ngrx/store`, I'm checking a value there. Which is pretty close to this proposed solution.